# Картинка вылезает за блок

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, img

Логотип должен быть внутри блока и не вылезать за пределы, как сделать так чтобы картинка обрезалась находясь за пре[image: делами? Спасибо.]

```
body {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin: 30px 375px 20px 375px;
}

header {
    height: 154px;
    width: 1170px;
    left: 375px;
    top: 30px;
}

.logo {
    height: 54px;
    width: 261px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #F0BF5F;
}

.logoSvg {
    margin-left: 180px;
    display: inline;
}

.line {
    display: inline;
    background: #F5D494;
    height: 38px;
    width: 1px;
    margin-left: 168px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header {
  height: 154px;
  width: 1170px;
  left: 375px;
  top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden; /*именно этот стиль и обрежет все что выходит за грани блока*/
}
```